# 2007 Pontiac torrent wont start

Tags: pontiac, torrent

When I turn on the key the dash lights up with lights and the stabilitrac light is on. It says service vehicle soon. My radio and heater fan work but nothing else. No headlights or interior lights. Oh have changed the ignition switch battery and starter and still nothing what could it be?

Comment: Have you checked the starter relay.